# Graphhopper - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call load or importOrLoad before routing

Tags: graphhopper

I have developed and API which uses Graphhopper, and deployed it on a test server. I tested it and it works correctlty.

The problem is that when uploading the same project to another server, when I make an API request it crashes, showing this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call load or importOrLoad before routing

I put the same files in both servers:

- "map" folder containing "spain-130901.osm.pbf" file
- "data" folder containing this files:

  - properties
  - nodes
  - names
  - locationIndex
  - geometry
  - edges

So, what could be the problem? It crashes in one server and works well in the other one...

Comment: Please include the log of the server when it starts up. See if there are problems.

Comment: Nothing is wrong... This is the log output when I deploy de Graphhopper API:
"10-sep-2014 12:05:49 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Despliegue del archivo /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/graphhopper.war de la aplicación web"

Comment: On the server you do not need map folder etc. On Android we have a problem properly downloading the graph leading to the same warning: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/251 BUT you are on the server which is obviously not the same. The problem you describe is because of a loading of the graph which failed. Causes could be that you specified wrong graphhopper storage location or your filesystem is read only etc. Normally something that GraphHopper logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was related with permissions.